# Keras Model returning same result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a simple ANN model using Keras, trained it and saved it using the model.save() method. I then went on to load the model in a flask application using load_model() method however when i run the model i keep getting a 1.0 for each and every prediction i run it however when i load it within syder IDE i get proper results.

I have tried running the model using a tensorflow backend instead of a theano backend and now i am getting a completely different error,

```
 File "/Users/achimmunene/development/heartapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2797, in 
 _as_graph_element_locked
    % (type(obj).__name__, types_str))
TypeError: Can not convert a TensorVariable into a Tensor or Operation.
```

Comment: This save/load model has been bugged since I know keras. I can simply never use it....

Comment: Please add some code of your script